# material ui picker with formik with class component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have `@material-ui/pickers` with Formik in my React class component whenever I am trying to change date & time from picker I am getting below error

> TypeError : Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Below is my code

```
// Handle fields change
handleChange = input => e => { 
 this.props.formikHandleChange(e);
 this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
};

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
   <DateTimePicker 
        label="Creation Date"
        name={creationDate}
        onChange={handleChange('creationDate')}
        value={values.creationDate} 
        onBlur={formikHandleBlur}
   />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use formik  setFieldValue

```
  onChange={(date) =>
           setFieldValue(
             'creationDate',
                date
              )}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Handle fields change
handleChange = (e, input) => { 
 this.props.formikHandleChange(e);
 this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
};

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
   <DateTimePicker 
        label="Creation Date"
        name={creationDate}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,input)}
        value={values.creationDate} 
        onBlur={formikHandleBlur}
   />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

You can set the property with `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`

Comment: Getting `undefined` for name. `handleChange` is in different file and picker in different file. I am accessing `handleChange` via props.

Comment: updated answer. my bad didnt realised the name is an variable rather than a string.

Comment: I tried but getting same error mentioned in actual question.